# Rush Monorepo - Shared dependency is duplicated in node_modules

Tags: rush

I'm using [Rush](https://rushjs.io/) to manage a monorepo, in which multiple packages depend on `react-redux`. They both specify the exact same version in their package.json file.

Project A:
[image: Package dependency screenshot]

Project B:
[image: Package dependency screenshot]

Project B also depends on Project A.

I would expect that since they both use the exact same package version, that they would both link to the same folder in common/temp/node_modules/.pnpm. But instead they are linked to two different folders, with some random string (maybe a hash?) appended:

[image: Screenshot of node_modules with duplicate react-redux package]

This breaks things since Package B creates the redux `<Provider>` but when it calls functions from Package A, they look for the context created by one of the versions of react-redux but Package B initialised the provider with the other version.

Why is Rush making two copies of this same version? How can I prevent it from doing this and make both packages point to the same copy?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue - Disable `useWorkspaces` in `rush.json`